# Regex errors utilizing Tweepy in python

Tags: python, regex, url, tweepy

I am having a problem with the bit of code shown below. My original code worked when I was just puling the tweet information. Once I edited it to extract the URL within the text it started to give me problems. Nothing is printing and I am receiving these errors.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Evan\PycharmProjects\DiscordBot1\main.py", line 22, in <module>
get_tweets(api, "cnn")
File "C:\Users\Evan\PycharmProjects\DiscordBot1\main.py", line 18, in get_tweets
url2 = re.findall('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', 
text)
File "C:\Users\Evan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\re.py", line 241, in findall
return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
```

I am receiving no errors before I run it, so I am extremely confused about why this is not working. It will probably be something simple as I am new to using both Tweepy and Regex.

```
import tweepy
import re

TWITTER_APP_SECRET = 'hidden'
TWITTER_APP_KEY = 'hidden'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(TWITTER_APP_KEY, TWITTER_APP_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)


def get_tweets(api, username):
page = 1
while True:
    tweets = api.user_timeline(username, page=page)

    for tweet in tweets:
        text = tweet.text.encode("utf-8")
        url2 = re.findall('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA- 
F]))+', text)
        print(url2)


get_tweets(api, "cnn")
```

Errors again:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Evan\PycharmProjects\DiscordBot1\main.py", line 22, in <module>
get_tweets(api, "cnn")
File "C:\Users\Evan\PycharmProjects\DiscordBot1\main.py", line 18, in get_tweets
url2 = re.findall('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', 
text)
File "C:\Users\Evan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\re.py", line 241, in findall
return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Tell me if you need more information to help me, any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably don't post your actual credentials.

Comment: Thanks didn't catch that, I'll regenerate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting that error because you are using a string pattern (your regex) against a string which you've turned into a bytes object via `encode()`.

Try running your pattern directly against `tweet.text` without encoding it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion, it ended up working! I guess I overlooked that error message.